Installing a chimney cap - DIY vs. Pro
This chimney is missing a chimney cap.
The task of putting on a chimney cap itself seems like a simple task, but the concern is safely accessing the top of the chimney on a steep roof.
Is this something that can be done safely by a layperson, or best to hire a roofer?


If you were to fall, would the result be worth the money saved?

The task is fairly straightforward.
The risk of injury is obvious.
We don't know what precautions you intend to take, or what experience you have. I've worked on roofs at that height, but generally not that steeply pitched, and I'm less comfortable doing it now than when I was 20; I'd hire someone. Among other things, a pro is insured against the risks of causing other damage.

I too put a cap on my chimney atop a 2nd story 12:12 pitch roof. 30 years ago. Today, I'd call my son over (who is now the same age I was then) and make him get up there. I also had an extension ladder with stabilizers that I hooked over the ridge to get up/down, and my chimney was within easy reaching distance when straddling the ridge, yours doesn't look to be. Again, it's up to you to determine how much risk you're willing to take.

Please see the [help]. This is an opinion poll and depends entirely on your skillset, tools, and motivation, not to mention your personal definition of "safe".

I'd think it would be much better to hire an experienced/insured chimney person to do the install.  Maybe if it were a much shallower pitch with a shorter chimney that could be reached without needing a ladder or other additional lift it might be somewhat doable.  But for what's shown in the picture I wouldn't consider even getting on that roof, and I'm not afraid of being on roofs.  You'd need appropriate complete fall protection, and that doesn't mean just tying a rope around your waist and having a buddy on the other side of the house holding the rope.
I'd recommend hiring a chimney person and not just a general roofer.  The professional chimney expert could at the same time inspect and repair any problems on the chimney.  If this is an active chimney, it is important to have regular inspections and repairs to make sure the chimney is clear of soot, if there is a liner that it's in good condition, and make sure there isn't any damage on the top that would allow water intrusion or potential catastrophic failure at some point in the future.

Thank you for your detailed answer.
This chimney isn't actively used. The home inspector said it's not safe to use as a wood burning fireplace due to the condition but could install a gas line to use as a gas fireplace. I'd need to do more research on that.

If you want an active fireplace and convert it to gas, you'll need to get a chimney liner installed to prevent corrosive exhaust gasses from damaging the chimney internals, so it will be more than just running gas and installing a gas burning insert.  That's all doable, but it's a matter of how much it would cost.  In any case, if you do enlist the assistance of a chimney professional, since this is an inactive fireplace, you can also have them make sure the damper seals well so you don't get a lot of energy loss up the chimney.

If I don't have the budget to convert to a gas fireplace at this moment but maybe a couple of years down the road, how critical would you say it is to still put a chimney cap right now to prevent further damage or water intrusion?
Really appreciate your advice.
